# An error or a bug in overriding Visreg line colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've searched all over for an answer to this issue. I have a plot created in visreg, and I have successfully changed the line and point colors with the following code.

```
visreg(RTmodel, "Verb_Type", 
       by = "Trust_Untrust", ylab = "LogRT", gg = T, 
       points = F, overlay = T) +
  ggtitle("LogRT LME") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cb)
```

[image: LogRT Residuals Visreg plot]

Awesome, just the colors I wanted! But the legend to the side is shaded with the original colors used by base Visreg. So, it doesn't really work with the colors I've chosen.

I've tried the following solutions:

1. Entering `legend=FALSE` to get rid of the legend.
2. Adding `guides(color=guide_legend(title="Trustworthiness"))` to the end, but that only creates a legend with the correct manually entered colors AND keeps an empty legend with the filled in boxes! (I've also tried this with `legends=F` and no dice).

.

```
visreg(RTmodel, "Verb_Type", 
       by = "Trust_Untrust", ylab = "LogRT", gg = T, 
       points = F, overlay = T, legend = F) + 
  ggtitle("LogRT ~ Verb Type by Trustworthiness") + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = cb) + 
  guides(color=guide_legend(title = "Trustworthiness"))
```

[image: LogRT Residuals Visreg with Wrong Legends]

3. Entering `plot=FALSE` and creating a ggplot of the data visreg returns, but that comes with its own issues!
4. A previously given suggestion of adding one or a combination of the following:

.

```
fill=list(col=c("#56B4E9", "#D55E00")), 
point=list(col=c("#56B4E9", "#D55E00")), 
line=list(col=c("#56B4E9", "#D55E00"))
```

But I get the following error.

```
visreg(RTmodel, "Verb_Type", 
       by = "Trust_Untrust", ylab = "LogRT", gg = F, 
       points = T, overlay = T, legend = F, 
       fill = list(col = c("#56B4E9", "#D55E00")), 
       point = list(col = c("#56B4E9", "#D55E00")), 
       line = list(col = c("#56B4E9", "#D55E00")))
```

> ```
> Error in plot.visreg(v, ...) : 
> formal argument "points.par" matched by multiple actual arguments
> ```

I've tried every combination I can in the visreg code T/F changes (gg, plots, legend etc). And the only two packages I have loaded are Tidyverse and Visreg. I think ultimately, this might be a bug in the system.

Comment: This looks like a `fill` legend to me.  You could try `fill = "none"` within `guides()` to try to remove it.  You can verify that this is a fill legend by changing the color of the fill via `scale_fill_manual()`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much!